# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str - Python Code Error

Tags: python

I am getting an eror in the following code in Kaggle notebook. Anyh help on how can I fix this issue? Thanks!

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-706bade4c87d> in <module>
      1 char_dict = []
      2 for char in os.listdir(char_path):
----> 3     char_dict[char] = len(os.listdir(os.path.join(char_path,char)))
      4 
      5 # Sort in Descending Order

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 2):

You're defining `char_dict` as a list instead of a dict

```py
char_dict = {}
for char in os.listdir(char_path):
    char_dict[char] = len(os.listdir(os.path.join(char_path,char)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing string i.e, file's content names as the index.

```
char_dict = []
for char in len(os.listdir(char_path)):
  char_dict[char] = len(os.listdir(os.path.join(char_path,char)))
```